How to replace strings into a foreach before explode command usign PHP
I have a foreach where I extract football matches; the format of the football match string is like

Manchester City - Manchester United

and I use "-" to explode them, but I have a problem with some football team name because they have that character into the name, like

V-Varen Nagasaki

so I thought to replace the name without that character, like

"V-Varen Nagasaki","V Varen Nagasaki"

This is the webpage link: link
This is my part of code where I explode them:
`$c=0; $b=0; $o=0; $z=0; $h=0; $j=0; 
foreach ($titles as $match) {
    
   
    list($home, $away) = explode('-', $titles[$z++]->innertext); // <- explode


$home = strip_tags($home);
$away = strip_tags($away);
$uniquefield = $home . ' ' . $away;`
}

So, you can see I explode titles (football matches) in two variables list home and away,
but I am not sure where I have to put all my replaces teams list.
Every name is different so I can't do a general replace, but specific for each team
Thanks for your helping

Explode by ' - '…? But even that, should there be some Fruthberg - Leftham - Manchester, that's also no good…

yes, in Python, for example, I replaced every teams with "-", but I don't know how I can do it in PHP

…?! I'm saying you should explode by the string ' - ' (space hyphen space). That should split V-Varen Nagasaki - Manchester into V-Varen Nagasaki and Manchester.

Oh my God! It was my mistake, it's working now! Thanks!

If you want to put your answer into an official answer, I will give you the reward :)

If you have football match strings where team names might contain hyphens and you want to split them correctly, you can use a regular expression to dynamically handle the splitting. Here's how you can achieve this in PHP:
<?php
$titles = [
    "Manchester City - Manchester United",
    "V-Varen Nagasaki - Tokyo Verdy",
    "Real Madrid - Barcelona",
];

foreach ($titles as $match) {

    preg_match('/^(.*) - (.*)$/', $match, $result);
    if ($result) {
        $team1 = $result[1];
        $team2 = $result[2];
   
        echo "Team 1: $team1, Team 2: $team2\n";
    } else {
        echo "Invalid match format: $match\n";
    }
}

This approach ensures that team names with hyphens are correctly handled, making it robust for various team name formats.
